# ExtJS: Get file from Ajax post request response

Tags: javascript, php, extjs, fpdf

I try to make a way to generate pdf files from my extjs application. When my export button is clicked this Ajax request is fired

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'data/apppdf.php?class=Export&action=composerCSV',
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: 1200000,
    params: {
        id: id
    },

    success: function (response, opts) {
        // i don't know what to do here
    }
});
```

In my PHP file I make a pdf file using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) library like so

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
// fill my file
return $pdf->Output(null, "rapport" . date('Y-m-d_H:i:s'));
```

after the success of my request and the end of my script where the file is returned how do it make it available for user (how do i get the open / save popup, with a valid pdf file) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use this approach, although there may exists better solution:

- define browse window
- generate PDF file on server
- download and preview PDF file

ExtJS part:

```
Ext.define('Test.ReportWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    xfilename: '',
    xtitle: '',

    layout : 'fit',
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    maximizable: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.callParent(arguments);
        me.title = me.xtitle;
        me.add(
            {
            xtype: "box",
            autoEl : {tag : "iframe", src : me.xfilename}
            }
        );
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'data/apppdf.php?class=Export&action=composerCSV',
        method: 'POST',
        timeout: 1200000,
        params: {
            id: id
        },

        success: function (response, opts) {
            var r = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            if (r.success == true) { 
                var win = Ext.create('Test.ReportWindow', {
                    xfilename: r.filename,
                    xtitle: 'Show PDF file'
                });
                win.show();
            } else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Attention', r.errmsg);       
            };
        }
    });
});
```

PHP part:

```
<?
// Create and save file to disk. Return filename to ExtJS.
// Uncomment next line and generate PDF as you want.
/*
require('fpdf.php');

$filename = 'test.pdf';
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output('F', $filename);

// Exception or other way of error check:
if ($something_is_wrong) {
   echo "{
        success: false,
        errmsg: 'Something is wrong.'
   }";
   exit;
}
*/

echo "{
    success: true, 
    filename: '".addslashes($filename)."'
}";
?>
```

Notes: Tested with ExtJS 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is saving the file on your server, with an "F" as first argument in the output() function:

```
$folder = '../';
$dt = date('Y-m-d_H:i:s');
$pdf->Output("F", $folder . "rapport" . $dt);

return $folder . "rapport" . $dt;
```

Since you now know the path and filename, you can return this string and do with it whatever you want in your ajax success function.
Note that I store the datetime first, because it's possible the return time is not the same as when creating the filename.
Check out the Output page in the docs for more information: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm

Your Ajax success function can be something like this:

```
success: function (response, opts) {
    $('div.yourdiv').html(response);
}
```

This will replace all html in div.yourdiv with the response from the php file. In this case, the link to your file.

Another example:

```
success: function (response, opts) {
    location.href = response;
}
```

This will redirect the user to the file after creation.

This is one way to do it, I'm sure it is possible without saving the files.